# Set scrape interval in provisioned Prometheus data source in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am provisioning a Prometheus data source to grafana. When adding the data source via the UI, I can set a "Scrape interval", which seems to determine the granularity at which data is fetched from prometheus.

However, I could not find out how to set that value in the yaml file when provisioning the data source from a yaml file. I tried "scrapeInterval", but it did not seem to work.

The documentation just has a small example, but it does not have the value.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same problem and also tried `scrapeInterval`, to no avail.

After looking through the source code, I found that you can set it using the `jsonData.timeInterval` field of a `datasources` list item. Here is an example `datasource.yaml` file with this field set to `10s`:

```yaml
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
  - name: Prometheus
    type: prometheus
    access: proxy
    httpMethod: POST
    url: http://localhost:9090
    jsonData:
      timeInterval: 10s
```

I found this in the [`types.ts`](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/public/app/plugins/datasource/prometheus/types.ts) file, along with the rest of the configuration options for the Prometheus datasource.

Comment: Also you can probably use this table from docs as a reference: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#json-data

Answer (score -2):

You can set it with the parameter scrape_interval.

```
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
```

It can be global or inside any job.

Comment: This sets the scrape interval in prometheus itself. What this question asks for is the scrape interval parameter in the *prometheus data source* configuration in grafana.